# Multiple year values in one column

Tags: python, csv, date, columnsorting

Here is the dataframe I am using:
The column names are (from left to right):

Cols=['Familiy'.'Genus','Species','Latitude','Longitude','Region','Distribution','Year']

[image]

The column I am trying to split into a few columns is the far right one: 'Year'.

As you can see on the 3rd row of the image I added, there are multiple names and years.  This is a problem for many of my rows.  I am trying find a program that will delete all characters that are not year, and then add columns so that each year is in a different column.

So far I have figure out that this command will output all years without the characters, but there is no separation between the years after I do the command:

```
merged['Year'] = merged['Year'].str.replace(r'\D','')
```

and here is the output for that command:

[image]

I would imagine that if I could find a way to use this command, separate the years by commas, then I could distribute the values into different columns.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: pandas.Series.str.findall https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html

Comment: Thank you! this led me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out a "scruffy" solution.

Found out there was up to 7 time entries for the column 'Year' surrounded by text.

```
before = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[0]
after = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[1]
after2 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[2]
after3 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[3]
after4 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[4]
after5 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[5]
after6 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[6]
after7 = merged['Year'].str.split(';').str[7]

merged['Observation_1'] = before
merged['Observation_2'] = after
merged['Observation_3'] = after2
merged['Observation_4'] = after3
merged['Observation_5'] = after4
merged['Observation_6'] = after5
merged['Observation_7'] = after6
#merged['Year_8'] = after7

del merged['Year']

merged['Observation_1'] = merged['Observation_1'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_2'] = merged['Observation_2'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_3'] = merged['Observation_3'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_4'] = merged['Observation_4'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_5'] = merged['Observation_5'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_6'] = merged['Observation_6'].str.replace(r'\D','')
merged['Observation_7'] = merged['Observation_7'].str.replace(r'\D','')
#merged['Year_8'] = merged['Year_8'].str.replace(r'\D','')


merged
```

In summary I split each column before ; and then after each individual ;, put them in their own column labeled 'Observation_n', and then used the last command to take out all of the letters in each column individually.

Not very smooth but it got the job done..